# Melt ~80gb Dist Matrix in R - Strategies for Efficiency?

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, r-bigmemory, large-data

Friends,

I calculated a distance matrix between researchers with igraphs shortest.paths on an undirected graph resulting in a 80gb matrix. 
Next step is to melt upper triangle of the matrix. I need to define this type of matrix on 16 different graphs.

When trying to run any operation (data.table::melt, lower.triangle <- NA or is.infinite <- NA) on the matrix I got the "cannot allocate vector..." - error, even though running it on Amazon AWS r3.8xlarge with 244GiB RAM.

Strategies I have tested:

- split matrix and melt submatrixes: too time consuming (2 days per matrix) or memory consuming when in parallel
- convert into big.matrix: too time consuming (1 day per matrix)

Any ideas why I get the error even if I have 2-3 times of needed memory available
Which strategy to use for this size of datasets?

Thanks so much in advance!

Session info:

ami-b1b0c3c2 (from http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)

RStudio 0.99.903

R 3.3.1

r3.8xlarge - Instance

My code (df_Network has 2 columns: AuthorID and ArticleID):

```
  # Calculate dist.matrix

  A <- spMatrix(nrow=length(unique(df_Network$AuthorID)),
                ncol=length(unique(df_Network$Articleid)),
                i = as.numeric(factor(df_Network$AuthorID)),
                j = as.numeric(factor(df_Network$Articleid)),
                x = rep(1, length(as.numeric(df_Network$AuthorID))) )
  row.names(A) <- levels(factor(df_Network$AuthorID))
  colnames(A) <- levels(factor(df_Network$id))
  Arow <- tcrossprod(A)

  # Calculate weighted relations
  g1_weighted <- graph.adjacency(Arow, weight = T)

  # Simplify graph to remove self loops and multiples

  E(g1_weighted)$weight <- count.multiple(g1_weighted)
  g1_weighted <- simplify(g1_weighted)

  distMatrix_weighted <- shortest.paths(g1_weighted, v=V(g1_weighted), to=V(g1_weighted))

  # 1st option: melt Matrix (R crashes with each of the lines)

   distMatrix_weighted[upper.tri(distMatrix_weighted)] <- NA
   distMatrix_weighted[is.infinite(distMatrix_weighted)] <- NA
   A_weighted <- data.table::melt(distMatrix_weighted, na.rm = T)

  # 2nd option: split Matrix, only take upper triangle and manually built data.table in parallel (Takes 2 days to run as I cannot take too many in parallel due to memory, too expensive to run on AWS as I am just a student)

     AllData <- foreach(j=2:(ncol(distMatrix_weighted)-1), .combine=function(x,y)rbindlist(list(x,y)), .inorder=FALSE) %do%{
                B <- data.table(Var1 = colnames(distMatrix_weighted)[j],
                Var2 = rownames(distMatrix_weighted)[1:j-1], 
                value = distMatrix_weighted[1:(j-1), j] )
                B[!is.infinite(value) & value >0]
       }

# 3rd option: split Matrix and run dt.melt in parallel (Takes too long as I cannot take too many in parallel due to memory)

 sequence <- seq(1,ncol(distMatrix_weighted), 100)

  AllData <- foreach(j=1:(length(sequence)-1), .combine=function(x,y)rbindlist(list(x,y)), .inorder=FALSE) %do%{
    m <- distMatrix_weighted[sequence[j]:sequence[j+1],]
    m[!is.finite(m)] <- NA
    data.table::melt(m, na.rm =T)
  }
  # 4th option: bigmemory package to store and then run multiple in parallel. Conversion to big.matrix is running since one day with no output

  distMatrix_weighted <- as.big.matrix(distMatrix_weighted)
  ...
```

Link to example Data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eaud2np33e5y6iv/df_network_2000-2005.RData?dl=0

Comment: Maybe you can do something on the igraph end to provide it in a different format, like a three column table (node, node, distance) rather than a matrix? Re the memory usage, there is an issue filed that reports 4x object size is currently used https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1069

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the hint! a) I will check how to change output of igraph's shortest.paths, b) the article talks about 4x object size of dcast, melt shouldnt have more than twice the size as they report - I have 244GiB RAM and 80GB Matrix

Comment: If you have 80GB and you convert it to data.table, then you already use 160GB (assuming you are not removing matrix). You should include your code and example data. Using more compact format seems a good way to try.

Comment: Agreed with Jan, at the very least the two lines immediately before the `melt` attempt should `rm` everything else from your workspace and then `gc()` for good measure. Also, if you look at the code for `data.table::melt` you need your object to *already be a `data.table`* otherwise `reshape2::melt` will be called. So before the `rm();gc()` make sure your `m` actually is a `data.table` object.

Comment: @Gregor well spotted! `data.table::melt`, this may be the issue here. Us `as.data.table` before calling melt.

Comment: You may also want to check ```Matrix``` library.  For instance, ```dspMatrix```, symmetric real matrix with only one triangle stored seems an interesting option (if you use symmetric distance.)  Also, if you are running on AWS anyway, you may try some sort of distributed storage.  Check out ```pbdDMAT``` package.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I will try it out and report back.

Comment: as.data.table(), gc() and then data.table::melt results in "negative length vectors are not allowed" saying memory limit or at least too long vector. I ll check again with big.matrix and try out dspMatrix and the pbdDMAT package. Thanks again!

Comment: distMatrix_weighted <- as.big.matrix(distMatrix_weighted)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 80.9 Gb
Error during wrapup: long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:138

Comment: with pbdDMAT I couldn't find out how to apply melt-function. Converting to dspMatrix failed due to vector size. Any other hints? Thanks!